# Taking different perspectives. What grammar patterns are correct?

Tags: grammaticality

Are these correct sentences? And are they natural?

1. *"It was 10 years yesterday, since I have been working here."* (meaning I'm still working here. I'm in two minds as to whether this should be "had been working" since the verb in the main clause is in the simple past tense)
2. *"It’ll be 10 years tomorrow, since I have been working here."* (meaning I'm still working here and will be working here tomorrow)
3. *"It’s been 10 years today, since I have been working here."* (meaning I'm still working here)
4. "It’s 10 years today, since I have been working here." (I think it is more British English, meaning I'm still working here).

I know that I can rephrase the 1st sentence as "Yesterday I had been working here for 10 years.", the 2nd sentence as "Tomorrow I'll have been working here for 10 years (*or* I'll have worked)", and the 3rd as "I have been working here for 10 years today"

Corrections are welcome!

**Update:**

> When since introduces a state in the past that is still continuing in
> the present, we use a present perfect form of the verb after since and
> a present perfect form of the verb in the main clause:
>
> Since I’ve been back at work, I’ve been feeling great.
>
> Source:
> https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/since

I opted out for the present perfect continuous tense after *since* because I want to emphasize that the action is still continuing.

Here's some more information. Michael Swan's *Practical English Grammar* states:

> **In British English, present and past tenses are common in the structure
> *It is/ was... since...***
>
> *It's a long time since the last meeting. It was ages since that wonderful trip.*
>
> American English prefers perfect tenses in this structure.
>
> *It’s been a long time since the last meeting. It had been ages since that wonderful trip.*
>
> **since-clause: since we were at school**
>
> Since can be used as a conjunction of time, introducing its own
> clause. The tense in the since-clause can be perfect or past,
> depending on the meaning.
>
> Compare:
>
> - I’ve known her since we were at school together. I’ve known her since I’ve lived in this street.
> - You’ve drunk about ten cups of tea since you arrived. You've drunk about ten cups of tea since you’ve been sitting here.
> - We visit my parents every week since we bought the car. We visit my parents every week since we’ve had the car.

Comment: I would prefer 'It's been 10 years since I started working here.' _Since_ usually refers to a starting date or time.

Comment: I suggest you rephrase to avoid using "specific time referents" like "today" or "tomorrow" as the ***subject*** of an utterance including ***since*** to specify the duration between that time referent and some significant date/time in the past (when something happened or started). Even native speakers may struggle to construct an idiomatic utterance if they started with that "syntactically awkward subject" before thinking through how they're going to continue. You'll hear things like *Today **makes it** ten years since I started working here,* but there aren't really any "good" answers.

Comment: Personally, I don't much like that final Cambridge example: *Since I’ve been back at work, I’ve been feeling great.* I'm fine with *Since **returning to** work...* or *Since **I returned to** work, I’ve been feeling great,* because the text immediately following ***since*** refers to a specific action that took place at a specific time in the past. But ***I've been back at work*** doesn't do it for me there.

Comment: 4. is not "more British English". And 3. doesn't make much sense in any English. All those sentences mean different things so basically we would have to run through all the grammar rules to explain them. That's a bit much, isn't it?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I've rearranged my initial sentences. Do they look better now?

Comment: @FumbleFingers what about the future and the past? "Tomorrow it'll make ten years since I started to work", "Yesterday it made ten years since I started to work" - are these all the only idiomatic utterenses?

Comment: Like I said - *none* of them are very good. Imho, this is because if you start with "specific date" *(**Today, Tomorrow, Yesterday,...**)* as the "subject" of an utterance, there are no completely natural ways to link that subject to a ***since*** clause where the purpose of the utterance is to specify a ***duration*** (identifying the subject as a "significant milestone" in "time passed ***since*** some earlier event").